# Android - Same Alignment - Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, alignment

I am showing data in list view. I want all names in same alignment. I used weight because I do not want image to place most of screen. But with this way I cannot align images in same way. Here is how it looks. [image of page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlTU7.png)

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/food_icon" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cost"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/owner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView" />

        </LinearLayout>
       </LinearLayout>

  </LinearLayout>
```

I need help. Thank you...

Comment: Why have you got nested LinearLayouts? Can you post a sample of what you want it to look like?

Comment: android:gravity="left" use this for the menu text id

Comment: @Nick This is what I want actualy but also I want all names start at same aligment. Maybe I cannot explain it in English.I want names start in same X coordinate. For example look Joe and Stevekjflk do not start in same coordinate

Comment: @hareeshJ I did but it did not make any difference

Comment: Try taking out the two inner LinearLayouts. At best, they aren't doing anything and may actually be causing your problem.

Comment: @Nick of course it did not work. I want to be seen like this, just same alignment for names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/food_icon" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/menu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="0dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cost"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/owner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="TextView" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @haresshJ Thank you it worked. I can make little difference but this is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to set android:weight_sum of the parent view to the sum of the weights of the child views. For example, the first linear layout would have a weight_sum of 3 + 1 = 4.

Comment: You did not understand my question. You see the name next to image. For example Joe and Stevekjnl are not in same alignment.

Comment: Maybe the textview is centered, so you have to set the text alignment to left?

Comment: I write android:layout_gravity="left" for that purpose. It did not work.